# The Galois group of automorphisms on the splitting field of the polynomial x^5 - 11.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I think that the splitting field (the smallest subfield of C that contains all the roots of x^5 - 11) is Q adjoined with r and z where r is the real solution of x^5 - 11 = 0 and z is the 5th root of unity.  I think that the degree of r over Q is 5 because x^5 - 11 is the minimum polynomial of r over Q.  I think that the degree of z over Q(r) is 4 because the minimum polynomial of z over Q(r) is 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4.  Since each automorphism on Q(r,z) must map r to a root of x^5 - 11 and z to a root of 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 then there must be 20 elements in GalQ(r,z).  I looked at a list of subgroups of S_5 and there is only one of order 20.  It is <(12345),(2354)>.

An exercise in my textbook states: If f is an automorphism in this group, and f(r)=r*z and f(z) = z^3 write T(f) in cycle notation where r~1, r*z~2, r*z^2~3, r*z^3~4, r*z^4~5.  T(f) is f restricted to the roots of x^5 - 11.

I am not certain if anything I have stated above is correct.  I do not know how to complete the exercise.  The answer provided in the text is T(f) = (1254).

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you say is basically correct. Another way of concluding that the order of the Galois group is $20$ is to note that $[\mathbb{Q}(r,\zeta):\mathbb{Q}] = 20$. Also, the statement that the minimum polynomial of $\zeta$ over $\mathbb{Q}(r)$ is $1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4$ probably requires some justification.

As to your last question, note that since $f$ is a field automorphism, we have
$$f(r\zeta) = f(r)f(\zeta) = r\zeta\zeta^3 = r\zeta^4\sim 5.$$
The others are similar.